# Weird has_many :through new record form issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a regular for with checkboxes for my has_many :through relation. My problem is that  I can't create a new project and have checkboxes checked. I get a validation error "Users is invalid". This is really weird.

If I create a project with no user checked it works and I can check them when I'm editing the project.

```
- User.each do |user|
  %label.checkbox{title: user.email}
    = check_box_tag 'project[user_ids][]', user.id, @project.user_ids.include?(user.id)
    = truncate(user.full_name, length: 16)
```

So in short: I can edit projects but not create new ones. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I have three models, User, Project, Projectship where the latest is the relation between the others. It's when I'm trying to create a project and pass user relations to it my problem occurs. When editing everything works like a charm.

```
User
  id
  email

  has_many :projectships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects,     through: :projectships

Project
  id
  name

  has_many :projectships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :projectships

Projectship
  id
  user_id
  project_id

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  validates :project_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id,    presence: true
```

ProjectsController:

```
# GET /projects/new
def new
  @project = Project.new
end

# POST /projects
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)
  if @project.save
    redirect_to @project, notice: t('flash.project_created')
  else
    render :new
  end
end

  # GET /projects/:id/edit
def edit
  @project = Project.includes(:users).find(params[:id])
end

# PUT /projects/:id
def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
    redirect_to :back, notice: t('flash.project_updated')
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

private

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(
    :client_id, :currency, :description, :end_date, :estimated_hours,
    :fixed_price, :hourly_rate, :name, :start_date, :status,
    :billable_type, :user_ids
  )
end
```

P.S I'm using 4.0.0.beta D.S

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your model, can you share that? That ```User.create!``` in the console work?

Comment: I updated my question abit. It's when I'm trying to create a Project with "projectships" relations.

Comment: Just wondering how you are handing create vs update actions in your controller? Any differences?

Comment: Sounds like the most likely problem is that the users aren't valid.  Do the users have validations, and are you sure they're passing?

Comment: No I'm using "save" in create action and "update_attributes" in update action

Comment: @numbers1311407 The User model isn't active in this case, it's the model called Projectship who has two columns, user_id and project_id

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code for all three models? That'll speed things up.

Comment: I updated question with code from models and ProjectsController.

Comment: Were you able to get this one figured out @sandelius?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store `users_ids` the model needs to be saved and that's way it didn't work. So now I store the ids in the create action and than add them directly after I save the project.

Comment: Could it be you were stumbling upon this validation error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239640/rails-nested-attributes-does-not-create-parent/