# Rails nested attributes - does not create parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have the following models:

```
class Parent
  has_many :cars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars
end

class Car
  belongs_to :parent
  validates :parent, presence: true
end
```

The controller code:

```
def create
  parent = Parent.new
  parent.attributes = parent_params
  parent.save
end

def parent_params
  params.require(:parent).permit(:name,  cars_attributes: [:name])
end
```

When I try to create a `Parent` with `Cars`, the validation fails on the `Cars` because the `Parent` was not created yet. How can I make it pass validations when it's being created through nested attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a quick search, you could use `:inverse_of` to overcome this situation.

In your code:

```
class Parent
  has_many :cars, inverse_of: :parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars
end

class Car
  belongs_to :parent
  validates :parent, presence: true
end
```

(not tested)

Check out dem sources:

1. [Validating presence of the parent object](http://homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails/) (scroll to that part).
2. [Issue on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1629)
3. [Some post I didn't bother to read but is referenced on the issue above](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2815-nested-models-build-should-directly-assign-the-parent)

GL & HF.

Comment: Bingo! What actually worked was `has_many :cars, inverse_of: :parent` in the `Parent`. Thank you.

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk did you need the `inverse_of` part on the child class (Car)?

Comment: No, I just needed `inverse_of` in the `Parent`.